# A trouble about AFNetworking response with Protobuf

Tags: ios, afnetworking, protocol-buffers

this is my code：

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manger = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manger.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-protobuf" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
manger.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manger.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"application/x-protobuf"];
```

i want get data with type of 'protobuf' ,so i just set manger.requestSeriallizer and manger.responseSeriallizer like you see,but i can't get anything from serve,it's because AFNetworking need an explain for protobuf？or my method is wrong？
when i set requestSeriallizer and responseSeriallizer to JSON,i can get data from serve.

Comment: failure block is called?

Comment: success,but request nothing.
request json have data.